# How could I return a nullable value in typescript

Tags: typescript, nullable

in an NPM module I use typescript

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1"
  }
```

and I want to return a private nullable  parameter using a public method. Please refer to the axample below. 
The error I see is

```
Property 'string1' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

If I assign an undefinded in the constructor I got the error

```
[ts]
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How should I do this in typescript, I´m from the c# side :)

```
export class HowToDoThis {

    private string1?: string;

    public constructor() {

        //this.string1 = undefined;
    }

    public add2String1(content: string) {

        this.string1 += content;
    }

    public getString1(): string {

        return this.string1;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not assign your string a default value? also, `?` in TS means optional, not nullable, and a string is nullable so you can remove it.

Answer (score 36):

You can define

```
private string1: string | undefined;
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of "private string1?: string;" which is much more concise (1 additional char vs. 12 additional chars)...

Comment: Right but I prefer this more descriptive way to express it. Either way does not influence the final file size as these details are not passed to the generated js.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'` isn't because you assigned `this.string = undefined` in the constructor, it is because you defined `getString1()` as returning `string` and you didn't check that `this.string1` was in fact a string.

You can either change `getString1()` so it does in fact always return a string, or you could make it return `string|undefined`, or much simpler you could just initialise `string1` to an empty string and never have it undefined.

So this works:

```
export class HowToDoThis {
    private string1?: string;

    public constructor() {
        this.string1 = undefined;
    }

    public add2String1(content: string) {
        this.string1 += content;
    }

    public getString1(): string {
        return this.string1 || "";
    }
}
```

But this would be better if only because calling `add2String1('foo')` won't give you the string `'undefinedfoo'`:

```
export class HowToDoThis {
    private string1: string = "";

    public add2String1(content: string) {
        this.string1 += content;
    }

    public getString1(): string {
        return this.string1;
    }
}
```

And this is best of all (don't use getter functions in typescript, you can always create a `get` property later if you need to do something when a property is accessed):

```
export class HowToDoThis {
    public string1: string = "";

    public add2String1(content: string) {
        this.string1 += content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Not sure what you want to do? Why do you want it to be undefined? I don't think you want to concatenate content with "undefined".

So use:

```
private string1 = "";
```

or

```
private string1: string;
public constructor() {
    this.string1 = "";
}
```

Comment: I need to deal with undefined because the structure has a lot of parameters (trip planning usecase) not all are needed. And if not needed it should be undefined and not an empty string ""